# How to organize nested props in VueJS?

Tags: properties, components, vue.js

I have this strange organization/architecture pickle I can't seem to figure out.

Say I have 3 components, A -> B -> C where A is a grandparent, B is a parent, and C is a child.

A passes an array of objects to B.
B loops through the array passing each object to instances of C. 
Some of these objects are guaranteed not to change, while others may change.

C requires two fields in the object to be present, say object.name and object.icon. This would be specified in C's props.

My pickle is that a developer that is using component A has to look at C's props in order to know what properties to provide in the objects to B.  And this problem only gets worse if I add more components between A and C.

How do I structure this? 
I was thinking maybe this is where a store would come in, but I always thought stores were for maintaining state that can change.  And some of the objects that A provides are guaranteed to never change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would use a shared state among components, or as you said, a store. Stores are specially useful for when you want to maintain some data between components, and when it changes in any of those, it will update in all the other components.

Simple example:

```
var sourceOfTruth = {
  propThatChanges: {},
  immutable: {}
}

var vmA = new Vue({
  data: sourceOfTruth.propThatChanges
})

var vmB = new Vue({
  data: sourceOfTruth.propThatChanges
})
```

Now whenever `sourceOfTruth.propThatChanges` is mutated, both `vmA` and `vmB` will update their views automatically. In the case of the objects that are guaranteed to not change, you could simply not pass it to the C components, just like `sourceOfTruth.immutable`. Or you could create an entire new store object available to A but not B or C

There is more info the the Vue docs, you should check it out:
http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#State-Management

Comment: What would you do instead of passing the immutable data to the C components?

Comment: I updated the example to better show the immutable data in C components.